# Run script on nodeJS server under a memory limit

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a nodejs server deployed to heroku. It doesn't have much load except once a day, when it parses quite a big piece of data (~20mb JSON file).

It takes about 20 seconds on macbook pro.

Heroku starts complaining about memory limit `Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)` and eventually terminates the process.

How do i make the script to run under specified memory limit? It's okay if it will take few minutes instead of 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can test locally by setting `--max_old_space_size` to a limit that would fit within your dyno:

```
node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100 server.js
```

This question ("how can an unspecified JS program use less memory") is too broad to answer specifically. Generally, you need to allocate fewer objects simultaneously. Running your app locally should help you identify hotspots (you'll get allocation errors).